# Airflow KubernetesPodOperator - mount all files from one secret to a common directory

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

How should I mount all the files in K8s secret to a common directory on K8s pod

Currently I have 3 files on one secret: `my-secrets`

When I tried to do the following

```
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
secret_pem = Secret('volume', '/usr/share/certs/', 'my-secrets', 'root.pem')
secret_cert = Secret('volume', '/usr/share/certs/', 'my-secrets', 'client.cert')
secret_key = Secret('volume', '/usr/share/certs/', 'my-secrets', 'client.key')
```

I get the following error

```
[spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[1].mountPath: Invalid value: \"/usr/share/certs/\": must be unique, spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].mountPath: Invalid value: \"/usr/share/certs/\": must be unique]
```

It looks like all the volumes cannot be mounted to `/usr/share/certs` and each volume needs a unique path

What should be done to mount all the three files to same directory?

Would this help?

```
secrets = Secret('volume', '/usr/share/certs/', 'my-secrets')
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?